# Get smooth line plot by filling missing values

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, line-plot

I have multiple Dataframes (up to 30) which all contain timestamps with associated values. The timestamp in the DataFrames do not necessarily overlap and the recorded values can only stay the same or increase. A DataFrame may look like this:

```
            time   coverage  
0       0.000000  32.111748   
1       0.875050  32.482579   
2       1.850576  32.784133    
3       3.693440  34.205134 
...
```

I uploaded a couple of csv files with data here [1](https://pastebin.com/ggyfNPaE), [2](https://pastebin.com/WreykHEz), [3](https://pastebin.com/1pWpPqWy), [4](https://pastebin.com/HwMERXkw).

So what I am trying to do is to plot the increase of the mean and median coverage values over time for all recordings, as follows:

```
# data is a list of dataframes
keys = ["Run " + str(i) for i in range(len(data))]
glued = pd.concat(data, keys=keys).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Run'})
glued["roundtime"] = glued["time"] / 60
glued["roundtime"] = glued["roundtime"].round(0)  # 1 significant digit

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

my_dpi = 96
stepsize = 5
start = 0
end = 60

ax1.set_title("Mean")
ax2.set_title("Median")
f.set_size_inches(1980 / my_dpi, 1080 / my_dpi)

ax1 = sns.lineplot(x="roundtime", y="coverage", ci="sd", estimator="mean", data=glued, ax=ax1)
ax1.set(xlabel="Time", ylabel="Coverage in percent")
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
ax1.set_xlim(0, 70)

ax2 = sns.lineplot(x="roundtime", y="coverage", ci="sd", estimator='median', data=glued, ax=ax2)
ax2.set(xlabel="Time", ylabel="Coverage in percent")
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
ax2.set_xlim(0, 70)

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this.
[image: Coverage over time]

However, the curve should never decrease as the "coverage" values can never decrease either. The reason for this, I suspect, is that at certain points in time I only have recordings of some DataFrames with lower values and therefore the mean/median is also lower.

I tried to fix this by aligning the indices of all the DataFrames and filling missing values with previous recordings, before doing any of the previous code. Like this:

```
#create a common index
index = None
for df in data:
    df.set_index("time", inplace=True, drop=False)
    if index is not None:
        index = index.union(df.index)
    else:
        index = df.index

# reindex all dataframes and fill missing values
new_data = []
for df in data:
    print(df)
    new_df = df.reindex(index, fill_value=np.NaN)
    new_df = new_df.fillna(method="ffill")
    new_data.append(new_df)
data = new_data
```

The result however does change much and decreases at certain times. It looks like this:

[image: Coverage over time with forward filling]

Is this approach wrong or am I simply missing something?

Comment: You say *"filling missing values with previous recordings"*, but aren't you just filling with `nan`s instead?

Comment: Well, I first fill them with ```NaN``` and then want to override these with sensible values so I can calulate the mean/median. I figured that taking the value preceding or following the current timestamp made sense.

Comment: is the `.interpolate()` function on the column what you are looking for, after you have replaced the values with NaN?

Comment: I will try that :-) . However, I don't understand how there can be drops in the line plot even with the filled data, since the mean should stay that same.